# Using KStreams To Merge Records

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm working on my first Kafka Stream using Java and essentially I am trying to read records from one topic and then merge the values of a number of these records into a single record to be written to a separate topic i.e. batch up a series of records into a single record. Ideally this batch would be controlled by either record size or number of records but at this point would be happy to get a simple example working! I was thinking the KStream.groupBy function would be the basis for a solution but unable to come up with a working example

Comment: You can find some starting point here: https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/tutorial, https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/index.html

Comment: I would recommend to use the Processor API instead of the DSL for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a stream of events and want to merge those into a list based on a key, you can start with the basic example as below:

```
KTable<String, List<Object>> aggregatedMetrics = eventStream
        .selectKey((k,v)-> k // Pick your key here)
        .groupByKey()
        .aggregate(() -> ArrayList::new, 
         (key, value, aggregate) -> aggregate.add(value), arrayListSerde());
```